How to stop the entire upload process in Multer based on a condition?
I’m currently using Multer in my Node.js (Nestjs) application to handle file uploads. I have a requirement where I need to halt the entire upload process based on certain conditions, similar to how Multer’s limits object does.
For instance, when the fileSize property is set in the limits object and an uploaded file exceeds that size, Multer stops the whole upload process and throws an exception:
const upload = multer({
  limits: {
    fileSize: settings.maxSingleFileSize,
  },
});

I want to achieve a similar behavior but based on custom conditions. For example, I might want to stop the upload if a certain file type is detected or if a local variable (enableFileUpload) is set to false.
I’ve tried using Multer’s fileFilter function to reject files based on their type, but this would cause some problems on browser-side ( For instance, if I throw an error -> handle it -> res.redirect, the browser would not receive the redirection because it’s busy uploading the file(s).)
Is there a way that the entire upload process is halted  as soon as a file is rejected by a custom condition (in a way the browser understands)?
I am considering using a pipe to check for my custom conditions, but I would prefer to cancel the upload process directly by Multer if possible.
